# Why does Gmail now lose viewed new message state?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

When using Gmail, the first time in a tab (e.g. Inbox, Social, Promotional, and Forums) new messages get a `NEW` icon before the subject line of each message that is new since the last time you looked at the folder and, additionally, the folder tabs show a count of new messages. After the new messages are displayed for about two seconds, the `NEW` designation is cleared and the tab header count is cleared.

About a week ago, the `NEW` designation started returning on messages previously cleared. When viewing messages it would clear, but if I returned back to Gmail later, having left it open in a Chrome tab, the `NEW` designation returns on messages that I have not read or not marked with a yellow star. On December 8, 2014 see this on messages going back to around December 3, 2014.

I am running Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) on Macintosh OS X Yosemite 10.10.1. I have a bunch of extensions: AdBlock 2.14.4, Copy Without Formatting 0.31, Mailvelope 0.11.0, rbutr 0.9.5.0, ScriptSafe 1.0.6.18, StumbleUpon 6.2.27.2, and Web Developer 0.4.6.

Why has the behavior changed and is there a way to correct it so that messages only show as `NEW` once?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your extensions and see what happens? (It looks like a bug to me—the action of removing the label is managed by JavaScript in the browser, but the changed state is not received by the server.)

Comment: Not yet, will try that next.  Since my set of extensions has not changed recently, I suspect an extension that was recently updated. Is there a way in Chrome to see the time of last update?

Comment: Are you using the browser's back button or refreshing the page? Is this even still happening?

Comment: No back button was used.  The issue went away and did not return.